# Why are there hiddent text nodes in this SVG element?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have 4 complex polylines in an SVG contained within a parent element (myLines). I want to store the polylines in an array in order to call them later in my code. For some reason the browser thinks there are hidden text nodes between the polylines within the "myLines" parent element. When I try to find the nodes in inspector using developer tools, the browsers says "some nodes were hidden", referring to these nodes.

However, when i use appendChild and move the polylines from one element to another the browser only detects the 4 polylines that are actually there.

What's going on here?

I've thought of a few work arounds to avoid this problem, but i'd rather know wtf is going on so i can actually fix it and learn what i did wrong.

```js
var main = document.querySelector('main');
var lines = main.querySelectorAll('g#myLines');
var element=document.getElementById("myLines2");
var elArray=[];
console.log(lines);
for (z=0; z<4; z++){
  console.log("lines[0].childNodes["+z+"]= "+lines[0].childNodes[z]);
  elArray[z]=(lines[0].childNodes[z]);
/*      element.appendChild(lines[0].childNodes[z]); */
   }
```

Please check out this fiddle of it. If you look in the console and enable this code "element.appendChild(lines[0].childNodes[z]);" on line 9, you can see that the text nodes don't appear using appendChild. 
https://jsfiddle.net/NZSIL/8psru5mv/

Thanks!!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question well, but I think those hidden text nodes are spaces, new lines and/or tabs that you use to format the html code to make it more readable. When you append elements to some parent element those tabs, new lines and spaces are not there because the elements are appended directly after each other without code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text nodes refer to the whitespace (newline characters) that are present in your SVG representation between the `polyline` elements.

Consider this example where we get a reference to group `g1` and check the number of child nodes. This example will print out `3`, referring to the whitespace before the `rect` element (text node), the `rect` element itself (element node), and the whitespace after the `rect` element (text node).

```js
const group = document.getElementById('g1');

console.log(group.childNodes.length); // 3 nodes
```

```html
<svg id="svg1">
  <g id="g1">
    <rect width="100" height="100"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In contrast, the snippet below will only count the `rect` element as a child node, because there is no whitespace between the `g` tags an the `rect` tags.

```js
const group = document.getElementById('g1');

console.log(group.childNodes.length); // 1 node
```

```html
<svg id="svg1"><g id="g1"><rect width="100" height="100"/></g></svg>
```

The common solution for cases like this, is to filter out the text nodes, and only work on the element nodes:

```js
const group = document.getElementById('g1');

const nodes = [...group.childNodes];

console.log(nodes.length) // 3 nodes

const elements = nodes.filter(n => n.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE);

console.log(elements.length); // 1 element
```

```html
<svg id="svg1">
  <g id="g1">
    <rect width="100" height="100"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

In the snippet above, all the nodes that are not element nodes (node type `Node.ELEMENT_NODE`) are filtered out, resulting in a one element array containing the `rect` node.

Comment: To increase readability you could use `n.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE`